# How to get Y coordinate of plot curve depending on its X coordinate (QWT)?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2, qwt

There's a code based on `QML` and `QWT`, kind of a graph maker with additional possibilities. One of the technical requirements is to get Y coordinate of a plot curve depending on some X coordinate.

There's an inaccurate way to do it - get the `QPoint` of `QwtPlotCurve` closest sample to some X coordinate.

```
int sampleIndex = curve->closestPoint(plotCanvas->mapFromGlobal(event->pos()));
QPointF sample = curve->sample(sampleIndex);
```

The most problem is that `QwtPlotCurve` can provide only samples coordinates, but I need to be able to get coordinates between samples as well. For example:

**[Explanation (image)]**

[image]

How to get Y curve coordinate if I know any X coordinate, not only sample?

Comment: Get the two closest sample points and interpolate between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to determine at least two points on each lines, then there is a mathematical solution to the problem. The complete explanation is here [Line–line intersection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93line_intersection)